# How can we use "who" properly in this context?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, who-whom

I want to say that parents are the decision makers about their child's marriage. Is it correct to say these sentences?

> Parents decide whom their children are going to (get married)/(marry).
>
> Parents decide on who is going to marry their children.

I want to formally write it.

Comment: Just say *Parents decide who marries their children* (or *...who their children marry*), and save yourself the awkward choice. No-one normally *wants* to use ***whom*** much these days, especially when it's easy to rephrase around the problem.

Comment: I'd use "*... to whom ...*" in your first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parents decide whom their children are going to marry.
>
> Parents decide [on] who is going to marry their children.

You don't really need *on* in the second one, but it's not wrong.